# Scale/Rotate a button in interface

Tags: iphone, button, rotation

I need to rotate a button by 30 degrees in iphones sdk interface builder, how do you do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rotate an UIImageView in Interface Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654096/how-can-i-rotate-an-uiimageview-in-interface-builder)

Answer (score 11):

You can't do it in Interface Builder, but the code is pretty straightforward.

Make sure you've connected the button in IB to an `IBOutlet` of type `UIButton*` (let's call it `myButton`). Then once the nib has been loaded (for example, in your `viewDidLoad` method) you can use something like this:

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity,
         RADIANS(30.0));

myButton.transform = rotateTransform;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do it directly. You might be able to do it if you were drawing your own buttons via CoreGraphics layers.

[Core Animation Layers](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
             [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    button.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((0.0174532925)*30);

    //put the -ve sign before 30 if you want to rotate the button in the anticlockwise else use this one 

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```