# How can I rotate an UIImageView in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, rotation, interface-builder

Is it possible to rotate an UIImageView in Interface Builder from XCode? Like I can do it in Photoshop, where I can scale and rotate an image.

I know it is possible by code but is there a way to do this in the interface builder?

Comment: false ... Xcode allows you to bind any "action" you like using runtime parameters. Read my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this in the current version of Xcode. You may submit a feature request to Apple at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

However if you want to do it, you will need to write some code

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

theView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(theView.transform, radians)
```

Comment: that's a little bit annoying, thanks for your code snippet ;-)

Answer (score 38):

Yes, you can do this in interface builder without any additional code with `layer.transform.rotation.z` runtime attribute. Note that this value is in radians.

[image: rotation]

Comment: useful, if anyone need converter : https://aci-birimleri-cevirici.hesabet.com but it is turkish

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can but using a little trick.

Declare in your code a new UIView Category like this

```
@interface UIView (IBRotateView)

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat rotation;

@end


@implementation UIView (IBRotateView)
@dynamic rotation;

- (void)setRotation:(CGFloat)deg
{
    CGFloat rad = M_PI * deg / 180.0;

    CGAffineTransform rot = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad);

    [self setTransform:rot];
}

@end
```

Now you can use a runtime parameter "rotation" directly on interface builder like this on any UIView you like.

[image]

Obviously interface builder will not rotate the view in its internal render because it will only effect the runtime rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Nope thats not possible in the interface builder but the code is quite simple:

```
#define RADIANS(degrees) ((degrees * M_PI) / 180.0)

CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity,
     RADIANS(120.0));

imageView.transform = rotateTransform;
```